# Error using class from different project in Data Template wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel, datatemplate

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding OpenTabs}" Grid.Row="1">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:HomeViewModel}">
                    <views:HomeView />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type instructor:CourseManagerViewModel}">
                    <instructorViews:CourseManagerView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
```

I have the code above in my MainWindow.xaml in Project A, but whenever I run it, it blows up on the  with an error 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception. I discovered that it works when I remove the

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type instructors:CourseManagersViewModel}">
                    <instructorViews:CourseManagerView />
                </DataTemplate>
```

The CourseManagersViewModel and CourseManagerView is defined in Project B, but which is referenced in Project A(main project). How do I correctly reference a ViewModel/View defined in a different project from the DataTemplate

Comment: Can you include the definitions for your instructors and instructorViews namespaces

Comment: xmlns:instructor="clr-namespace:Tutor.Instructor.ViewModel;assembly=Tutor.Instructor"
        xmlns:instructorViews="clr-namespace:Tutor.Instructor.Views;assembly=Tutor.Instructor"